# When can I say a network converges better?

Tags: neural-networks, convergence, stochastic-gradient-descent

I trained two networks with and without skip connection. The network is a FCNN and has an encoding-decoding structure.

I trained the networks with SGD and MSE for 150 epochs. The attached image is a comparison between validation RMSE. The RMSE for the network with the skip connection (network II) is slightly better than the one without skip connection (network I).

[image]

- Given that it is trained with SGD can I take this improvement as an actual improvement or could it be random because of SGD? (I trained the networks several times and always network II reaches lower error)
- Does this look like a convergence at all? If I go further epochs the fluctuations persists (I guess because of SGD there is a fluctuation) and RMSE doesn't improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this look like a convergence at all? If I go further epochs the fluctuations persists (I guess because of SGD there is a fluctuation) and RMSE doesn't improve

Fluctuations will always occur in SGD unless you employ some schedule that reduces the learning rate. Despite these, since the trend of the loss isn't downward, we usually call this "convergence".

> Given that it is trained with SGD can I take this improvement as an actual improvement or could it be random because of SGD? (I trained the networks several times and always network II reaches lower error)

From what I can see by the figure, the slightly lower loss can most certainly be attributed to SGD noise. To be certain that Network II is better than I you can perform some statistical analysis on the results, i.e. train both multiple times and see if the difference in the values is statistically significant.

Comment: how many times would you define as multiple times? 5,10,50? (as  a rule of thumb...)

Comment: Depends on your resources and the variance exhibited in each experiment. I've done this a couple of times and used 25-30 runs per experiment. However, if each run is computationally expensive (e.g. 1 day), this isn't ideal. Also you might see that the first 5-10 runs have almost no variance (their curves are almost identical), so it doesn't make sense to run any more.